# Move SQL Server Unicode XML column to Oracle via Base64 document

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle, base64, decode

Problem:
When I decode and reconstitute my base64 encoded XML document, I get null values between each character.  I think I need to convert to NCHAR, but it's not working as expected.

```
Block   : PgA8AC8AYwBsAGkAbgBpAGMAYQBsAF8AcwB0AHUAZAB5AD4A
Decode  : 3E003C002F0063006C0069006E006900630061006C005F00730074007500640079003E00
Varchar2: > < / c l i n i c a l _ s t u d y
Raw2NHex: 3E003C002F0063006C0069006E006900630061006C005F00730074007500640079003E00
```

(Note: The blank characters on the Varchar2 output are actually nulls.

Background:
I am having difficulty reading an XML data column from a base64 encoded element in an XML document that I build in SQL Server.

Basically, we are moving an XML document from one system to another, and had to use Base64 because Unicode < characters that were not < tag characters were being translated as `&lt;`.  Namely the text said < 3 months, using the unicode less than sign.

So, we translated the xml document into Base64 which worked great.
Sample XML Document

My Oracle decode function is this

```
v_clob := '';
v_offset := 1;
FOR i IN 1 .. ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob_in) / v_buffer_size) LOOP
  --
  --  Substr is 1-relative.
  --
  dbms_lob.read(p_clob_in, v_buffer_size, v_offset, v_buffer_base64);
  --
  IF v_buffer_base64 IS NULL THEN
    EXIT;
  END IF;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Block   : ' || SUBSTR(v_buffer_base64, 1, 80));
  --
  --   Decode the Base64 into a RAW string
  --   ... This works as expected
  --
  v_buffer_decode := utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_buffer_base64));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Decode  : ' || v_buffer_decode);
  --
  --  Cast the RAW output into VARCHAR2
  --   ... This results in null characters between each character
  --
  v_buffer_varchar2 := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(v_buffer_decode);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Varchar2: ' || v_buffer_varchar2);
  --
  --  Convert the decoded RAW string into NVARCHAR
  --  ... This doesn't actually do anything, it just puts out the same RAW characters.
  --  ... I get the same result as I do with RAWTONHEX.
  --
  SELECT CAST(v_buffer_decode as NVARCHAR2(1024)) 
         INTO v_buffer_nvarchar2
  FROM dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CastNVC : ' || v_buffer_nvarchar2);
  v_clob := v_clob || v_buffer_nhex;
  --
  v_offset := v_offset + v_buffer_size;
  --
END LOOP;
```

What I need is something that can take the 2-byte NCHAR and represent it as the proper single NCHAR value in the NVARCHAR2 variable.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this and reviewing the debug statements, I came to the realization that Microsoft and Oracle treat the high order byte of wide character sets differently.

In Microsoft, the binary is rendered as 3E00.  However, if you use
 
`select '*' || utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2('3e00') || '*' from dual`
You get `*㸀*`.  If, however, you do 
`select '*' || utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2('003e') || '*' from dual`
You get `*>*`.  Which is the proper conversion.

So, what I had to do was to extract characters from the decoded RAW string and flip the low-order and high-order bytes so that 3E00 became 003E.  I also, in the end, had to skip the FFFE base64 prefix from the binary data since Oracle didn't throw it away.
Here is the final code.

```
FUNCTION decode_base64(p_clob_in IN CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
--
v_clob             clob;
v_result           clob;
v_offset           number;
v_buffer_size      binary_integer := 48;
v_buffer_base64    varchar2(1024);
v_buffer_decode    RAW(1024);
v_buffer_varchar2  VARCHAR2(1024);
v_buffer_nhex      nvarchar2(1024);
v_buffer_nvarchar2 nvarchar2(1024);
v_buffer_nchar     NVARCHAR2(4);
v_buffer_convert   RAW(4);
--
BEGIN
--
IF p_clob_in IS NULL THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;
--
dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob, true);
--
v_clob := '';
v_offset := 1;
FOR i IN 1 .. ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob_in) / v_buffer_size) LOOP
  --
  --  Substr is 1-relative.
  --
  dbms_lob.read(p_clob_in, v_buffer_size, v_offset, v_buffer_base64);
  --
  IF v_buffer_base64 IS NULL THEN
    EXIT;
  END IF;  
  --
  --   Decode the Base64 into a RAW string
  --
  v_buffer_decode := utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_buffer_base64));
  --
  --  Convert the decoded text into NVARCHAR2 characters
  --  Note: Microsoft and Oracle disagree on high byte first or second
  --  Take out each character (4 characters) and flip the 3rd and 4th hex character to the front
  --  Thus, 3E00 becomes 003E
  --  Note: We have to ignore Microsoft's Base64 prefix code of FFFE.  (FEFF when extracted :) ).
  --
  v_buffer_nvarchar2 := '';
  FOR J IN 1 .. ceil(LENGTH(v_buffer_decode) / 4) LOOP
    --
    v_buffer_convert := SUBSTR(v_buffer_decode, (J - 1) * 4 + 3, 2) || SUBSTR(v_buffer_decode, (J - 1) * 4 + 1, 2);
    IF v_buffer_convert <> 'FEFF' THEN 
      v_buffer_nchar :=  utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(v_buffer_convert);
      v_buffer_nvarchar2 := v_buffer_nvarchar2 || v_buffer_nchar;
    END IF;
    --
  END LOOP;
  v_clob := v_clob || v_buffer_nvarchar2;
  --
  v_offset := v_offset + v_buffer_size;
  --
END LOOP;
--
v_result := v_clob;
dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_clob);
RETURN v_result;
--
END decode_base64;
```

That was the fix.